# Filtering a string by for loop word by word

Tags: javascript, for-loop, replace

I'm trying to create a for loop that will eventually return a filtered string after deleting unwanted words.

for example when given **red yellow green black blue white** I want the output to be **red green blue**

```
const givenString = 'red yellow green black blue white';
const unwantedWords = ['yellow', 'black', 'white'];

for(i = 0; i < unwantedWords.length; i++){
   let finalString = givenString.replace(unwantedWords[i], '');
   console.log(finalString)
}
```

The issue is this returns multiple logs, each with one of the three words removed. Not a final log with all words removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit

Just wanted to share a beautiful one liner of ES6.

```
const result = unwantedWords.reduce((prev, current)=>prev.replace(current,''), givenString);
```

You are defining the variable inside the loop everytime, so essentially you are just filtering out and discarding it. You should define it outside of loop and change it within the loop.

```js
const givenString = 'red yellow green black blue white';
const unwantedWords = ['yellow', 'black', 'white'];
let finalString = givenString;
for (i = 0; i < unwantedWords.length; i++) {
  finalString = finalString.replace(unwantedWords[i], '');
}
console.log(finalString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `givenString` is not changing. `finalString` is changed every time assing new change to `finalString` from `givenString` every loop.

```js
const givenString = 'red yellow green black blue white';
const unwantedWords = ['yellow', 'black', 'white'];
let finalString = givenString;
for (i = 0; i < unwantedWords.length; i++) {
  finalString = finalString.replace(unwantedWords[i], '');
}
console.log(finalString)
```